# Website images keep reloading on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a landing page which is a few sections with images as the background. Each section takes up the size of the screen. In one of the sections the images change every 5 seconds.

My website loads and works fine on Desktop (as far as I can tell).
However on mobile as I scroll up and down the page it keeps on reloading.

For example: I'm looking at section 2 that has been loaded. I scroll down to section 3 and it's still loading. Once it's loaded I scroll to section 2, section 2 begins reloading even though the it's the same image there.
No matter how much I scroll up and down this happens.

I am using bootstrap 3, jQuery (not jQuery mobile) and HTML5

*Note, section 1 has images that keep on swapping in and out. I load those images in the background before replacing the old image by:

```
var imgPreload = new Image();
$(imgPreload).attr('src', '/new-image.jpg').load(function() {
    $(this).remove(); // prevent memory leaks
    $('#section1').css('background-image', 'url(/new-image.jpg)');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple pure css slideshow for your first section?

[pure Css3 slideshow](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-css3-slideshow-with-image-panning-and-zooming-effect/) for me is a simple but good solution for fullscreen background image.

On which mobile device has been tested?

I encountered this problem on iPad (4th generation), iPad (3rd generation) and some iPhone 5C and 5S.

What's the images size? They have been appropriately compressed?

I partially solved by reducing the images size

Comment: you can add this notes as comment this is not an answer .

Comment: I know, but I don't have 50 rep, and It'ss the only way to respond. If necessary, I remove immediately

Comment: FilippoLcr thanks, I didn't know about that, thank you. I only tested on iphone 4S and OnePlus One (failed on both).  Hopefully now you're closer to having enough rep to leave comments btw =)

Comment: Thank you, if you can, try on the latest Iphone and see if the problem occurs, and with other devices, of course.  I've coded two site with bootstrap, and I've seen that in general problems arise with iOs portable devices (but I haven't possibility to testing on many multiple devices). If you use jQuery function like $.animate(), consider to implement  [Velocity.js](http://http://julian.com/research/velocity/)